# hibernate closing connections or not?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, connection

My code is below. Possibly I am using it many times in similar manner, i.e in simple words, I am managing the session and transaction this way:

```
 List<Login> users= null;
        try{
            session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            tx=session.beginTransaction();
            users=session.createQuery("from Login").list();
            tx.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("commit exception:"+e);
            try {tx.rollback();} catch (Exception ex) {System.out.println("rollback exception:"+ex);} 
        }finally{if(session!=null && session.isOpen()){session.close();}}
        return users;
```

Now, when I first run the database service(using MySQL) and check from command prompt using this query ...

```
show status like 'Conn%';
```

... the result is:

```
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| Connections   | 2     |
+---------------+-------+
```

When I start my application and use it. After opening few pages and querying the same thing. I am getting the connections as 6, I have even seen above 20.

Now I would like to know that hibernate is closing the connections or not?

I am handling all the transactions that way, I cross checked and dint see any code block without closing the session.

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>
        <property name="connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shareapp
        </property>
        <property name="connection.username">pluto</property>
        <property name="connection.password">admin</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">
            org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
        </property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>


    </session-factory>
```

hibernateutil class

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
        config.addAnnotatedClass(Login.class);
        config.addAnnotatedClass(FilesInfo.class);
        config.addAnnotatedClass(FilesShare.class);

        config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
     //   new SchemaExport(config).create(true,true);

        sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: how do you establish a JDBC connection? Are you using pooled connection or not? post the datasource config please

Comment: oh sorry i added it now please have a look. :)

Comment: could you also post the code of the class HibernateUtil?

Comment: so is there anyone who will answer this, i changed the database connection to jndi data source in hibernate.cfg but still no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Connections" status variable just refers to the

> The number of connection attempts (successful or not) to the MySQL server,

and not the number of active connections.
Here is the link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections

To get the number of open connections, check the 'Threads_connected' variable, documented at
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Threads_connected

Comment: By the way, if you use c3po for connection-pooling, you could probably use [Connection Customizers](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/ConnectionCustomizer.html) to keep track of connections from your code; a little more explanation can be found [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#connection_customizers)